# Stack Bar chart D3 without Time property

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot a Stack bar chart in D3 for a JSon of this format

```js
[{
    "Name": "John",
    "Running": 30,
    "Swimming": 0,
    "Cycling": 25
  },
  {
    "Name": "May",
    "Running": 25,
    "Swimming": 25,
    "Cycling": 0
  },
  {
    "Name": "Pemp",
    "Running": 25,
    "Swimming": 25,
    "Cycling": 50
  }]
```

Similar to this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q5q6331p/173/

But with the above fiddle, I'm not able to remove the time format. How Can I plot the chart without the time property.

Thanks.

Comment: Then, Instead of time what do you want? or do you want no X-axis at all?

Comment: Just as a text; nothing to do with time.

Comment: Then what text? Does that text come from your provided data?

Comment: Just as 2006, 2007; In line 103, `x: parse(d.year)` as `x:d.year`
and remove `var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `Year` only as a text in your X-axis, not as a `Time`, and also want to remove the time function from the script.

I have made a few modification in provided script by removing all the `time` functionality.

In the `dataset` variable where you map X and Y axis, I simply remove `parse(d.year)` and added `d.year`.
Also, at `xAxis` variable, which call a function to draw a method, I removed the `tickformat` specification. It works as expected.

You can find your modified code here : http://jsfiddle.net/vdzm8w0r/

Comment: How could I have missed that! tickformat on xAxis! Thank you.